# Custom Font for ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listactivity, typeface, custom-font

I have a class which is extended to the ListActivity for which I want to set a custom font. Can anybody walk me through this? I know how to use typeface of TextView but not for the ListActivity.

```
public static class PunjabiBooks extends ListActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] mathList = new String[] {"Gurmukh Soch", "Books (Punjabi)", "Books (Hindi)", "Books (English)",
        "Annual Report"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mathList));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        if (keyword.equals("Gurmukh Soch")){
            x = 0;
            try{
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("sukrit.trust.PublicationsTab$WebActivity");
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(PunjabiBooks.this, ourClass);
                startActivity(ourIntent);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(keyword.equals("Books (Punjabi)")){
            try{
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("sukrit.trust.Publications$PunjabiBooks");
                //  Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Publications.this, ourClass);
                //startActivity(ourIntent);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(keyword.equals("Books (Hindi)")){
            try{
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("sukrit.trust.PublicationsTab$HindiBooks");
                //                  Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Publications.this, ourClass);
                //                  startActivity(ourIntent);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(keyword.equals("Books (English)")){
            try{
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("sukrit.trust.PublicationsTab$EnglishBooks");
                //                  Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Publications.this, ourClass);
                //                  startActivity(ourIntent);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(keyword.equals("Annual Report")){
            try{
                Class ourClass = Class.forName("sukrit.trust.PublicationsTab$AnnualReport");
                //                  Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Publications.this, ourClass);
                //                  startActivity(ourIntent);
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A `ListView` doesn't inherently have any text to have a custom font for. You need to deal with the class which provides this text: the `Adapter`. Your adapter is responsible for creating the views in the `ListView` including (in this case) the `TextView` in question. You'll need to create a custom adapter (probably deriving from `ArrayAdapter<String>`) where you override the `getView` method. The simplest solution would probably be to simply call the parent implementation's `getView` and then to find the relevant `TextView` from the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout using `View.findViewById` (you can look it up, but I believe the relevant id is `text1`) and then doing the setting of custom typeface that you already know how to do. This probably looks something like:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    // Appropriate Constructor here
    // ...

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        // Do your textView.setTypeface( ... ) stuff here
    }
}
```